# JQuery doesn't work in Django custom templatetag's template

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

I am creating a simple custom templatetag that renders it's own template when called.  The problem is that the JQuery on this templatetag's template isn't working and I don't know why.

**Parent template**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% render_style %}
</body>
```

**render_style templatetag**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('TEST.html')
def render_style():
    return
```

**TEST.html**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#name").css("text-decoration","underline");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="name">FULL NAME</h2>
</body>
```

The templatetag's template is indeed loading because the text FULL NAME is displaying on the screen but its not being underlined.  If I put that same JQuery in the parent template, then FULL NAME would become underlined.

What's going on here?  It likes the JQuery when that script is in the parent class but it doesn't like it when the script resides on the render_style's template.

Comment: Wait... are you rendering a `<head>` and a `<body>` inside another `<body>`?

Comment: I think that was me trying anything to get it to work.  If I remove them nothing changes.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Nothing.  All my stylesheets and what not open fine and firebug's console doesn't show any errors.

Comment: Do you have a DOCTYPE? Without explicitly setting it to HTML 5, your browser might execute your jQuery `<script>` tags without a `type` attribute, like `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: When are you rendering the template, is it inside of another event?

Comment: The template loads when you reach the template tag {% render_style %}.  I'm gonna add that templatetag code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the template code is being executed in an event handler.

So your code adds an event listener to the `ready` event which has already executed once and will not be executed again.

So try moving 
`$("#name").css("text-decoration","underline");` 
under the `#name` tag and remove the ready event and see if it works.

Example:

```
<h2 id="name">FULL NAME</h2>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#name").css("text-decoration","underline");
</script>
```

Comment: When you remove the ready event make sure the script is added after `#name` or else it will try to select `#name` before it exists.